# How to fix 'Cannot set property 'props' of undefined' error

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I'm pressing button '&#60' or '&#62' (increase or decrease difficulty level) I get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined" at PureComponent (react.development.js:444)

How can I fix it?

The code above is much less then actual code, however even in this size it not works well.

Even 'blah-blah' do not appears in console.

**StartMenu.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import increaseDifficultyLevelfunction from './increaseDifficulyLevel';
import decreaseDifficultyLevelfunction from './decreaseDifficulyLevel';


function StartMenu(props) {
  return (
    <div className="start-menu-container">

      <button
        type="button"
        id="leveldown"
        onClick={decreaseDifficultyLevelfunction}
      >
      &#60;
      </button>

      <div id="level">{props.difficultyLevel}</div>

      <button
        type="button"
        id="levelup"
        onClick={increaseDifficultyLevelfunction}
      >
        &#62;
      </button>

      <button
        type="button"
        id="startButton"
        onClick={props.restartGame}
      >
        start the game
      </button>

    </div>

  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  difficultyLevel: state.difficultyLevel,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(StartMenu);
```

**decreaseDifficultyLevel.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { decreaseDifficultyLevel } from '../../actions/actionCeator';

function decreaseDifficultyLevelfunction(props) {
  console.log('blah-blah');
  props.decreaseDifficultyLevel();
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  difficultyLevel: state.difficultyLevel,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  decreaseDifficultyLevel: () => { dispatch(decreaseDifficultyLevel()); },
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(decreaseDifficultyLevelfunction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was digging into the details here and decided to try it in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/73j5w1pvzq).

The common React component (till hooks) cases, is made of a class component. In these cases, functions/actions are bind at the top level and retain their context in sub components (so we can use them). In function components, things are bit different. In order to get the actions to work you need to do the following:

1. link your actions to redux, using mapDispatchToProps as usual.

```
   Import * as actions from ’./actions’;

   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(levelActions, dispatch)
      };
   };
```

2. bind your actions so they can retain their context.

In order to make step 2, you need to declare the functions within the functional component (usually known as class variables) and then use them in the buttons onClick attribute. Like so:

```
   const {
     increaseDifficultyLevelFunction,
     decreaseDifficultyLevelFunction
   } = props.actions;

   const increaseLevel = () => increaseDifficultyLevelFunction();
   const decreaseLevel = () => decreaseDifficultyLevelFunction();
```

Check this [reference](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-redux-connect-when-and-how-to-use-it-f2a1edab2013), it covered your case with examples.

Comment: I am very appreciating your efforts, however - no luck. The main idea was to put into 'increa...Function' many actions, related with other game parameters. Moreover, it should be separated function because I need to use it with another components. In your example fun-n was turned into action and lost it functionality. I did new codesandbox  to show problem more clear and realised that codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/9zxmy33114  shows different type of the error. Now it is shows new type of error '_decreaseDifficulyLevel2.default is not a function'. Will be glad for any ideas.

Comment: somehow 'export default connect' did not recognized as a function.

Comment: . I tried you idea in a StartMenu component and in increaseDifficultyLevelFunction to combine it with another actions and get same error.

Comment: Finally the core of the problem is that somehow, 'export default connect...' after import become 'not a function' even console.log(typeOf) gives a 'function'.

Comment: Your example works now https://codesandbox.io/s/10vly5m5v3. follow the pattern I wrote in the answer. It should give you a sense how to structure your functions and avoid losing context.